# how to raise an even in angularjs within a specific time frame?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time, momentjs

I'm trying to compare the current time with a given start time and end time in order to show a message on the page when current time is between start and end time.

Let say stratTime = 10:30 AM and endTime = 1:30 PM; How can I be able to show a text message without user interaction on the page for that time frame, and not show it before or after? In a way that user won't need to refresh the page or do something else.

I'm using angularjs.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a look at moment's [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) and see how to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can get it to show the text message once the current time is between start and end time. The problem is I have to refresh the page after end time in order to hide the text. I'm hoping I could do it without relying on page refresh or user interaction!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$interval](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/api/ng/service/$interval) to run your test periodically and set a flag, change the text, or any other action when it passes.